# Uri syntax in ResourceDictionary Source (Universal Windows Platform)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, uwp

I'm migrating my `Windows 8.1` projects to `Windows 10` (Universal Windows Platform).
At this moment I was stopped by `ResourceDictionary` changes in `UWP`.

For simplicity:
I have Windows 8.1 solution with 2 projects:

```
App project (FooApp)+ Styles (FooStyles) project.
```

FooApp has reference to FooStyles, and in `App.xaml` I have:

```
<Application.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///FooStyles/Brushes.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

`ms-appx` syntax allowed me to access resource files from other projects.
Now in Windows 10 apps this is not working anymore. Compilation ends with the below error:

```
"An error occurred while finding the resource dictionary "ms-appx:///FooStyles/Brushes.xaml"."
```

Any advices here, to fix it?

P.S I would not move my resources from FooStyles to FooApp, because in my solution, FooStyles is shared between 5 other app projects.

Comment: This works great with UWP solution with 1 App project + 1 styles project. Check if your styles project supports win 10. And try to remove and re-add the reference to styles project in your app project.

Answer (score 6):

In UWP you must specify the namespace to achieve this. Also, I've found XAML Resource Dictionaries only reference this way if they are marked "Page" in the Property section.

Then in your Application xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Default.Namespace.External.Assembly/FolderPathOffRoot/Brushes.xaml"/>
        </Application.Resources>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

And don't be confused about ms-appx, it refers to your package, not just the project containing the application.