# MediaElement set Source property doesn't work

Tags: c#, windows-phone, win-universal-app, media, mediaelement

I'm trying to change `Source` property of `MediaElement` in my windows-phone application , I have two mp3 files in Assets file :

`"/Assets/fail.mp3"`

`"/Assets/success.mp3"`

when I set this proeperty in the designer to `/Assets/success.mp3"` for example, and invoke :

```
mediaElement.play();
```

the sound plays properly , but I want to change the source in my code and then play the sound again , I've tried these options :

```
mediaElement.Source = new Uri(BaseUri, "/Assets/fail.mp3");

mediaElement.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/fail.mp3", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

mediaElement.Source = new Uri("/Assets/fail.mp3", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

mediaElement.Source = new Uri("/Assets/fail.mp3");
```

but none of them works I got no error with no sound !, any one have an Idea what to do ?

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue. I changed the source via `mediaelement.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/test.mp3");`. It played well.

Comment: strange, did you immediately after this line tried ,  mediaelement.Play(); ?

Comment: I even have not called `Play()` method. It also played successfully.

Comment: no I set autoplay=false, and tried to invoke Play() in code

Answer (score 0):

This is UWP? Maybe you need to update your resource strings as shown here:
[Uri syntax in ResourceDictionary Source (Universal Windows Platform)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33033971/uri-syntax-in-resourcedictionary-source-universal-windows-platform/33046134#33046134)